After rebooting Ubuntu, wireguard clients can no longer connect to other hosts on my network
I'm a homelabber. I've had a WireGuard VPN running without incident for about 16 months. It runs on a Ubuntu Server installation within a VM. The hypervisor is byhve running on TrueNAS CORE.
Ever since I first set up WireGuard I've had an issue where clients are unable to connect to the public internet via the VPN. But since my primary purpose for setting up the VPN was just to be able to remotely manage my servers and access devices on my network, this wasn't a big issue. I used the AllowedIPs setting in the client config to only route traffic to my 192.168.10.0/24 subnet via the VPN, and traffic bound for the public internet doesn't touch WireGuard.
Recently I rebooted my Ubuntu VM. When it came back online I was able to connect to the WireGuard VPN, and through the VPN I can connect to any services running on my Ubuntu VM (192.168.10.240). However I am unable to connect to any other devices on my network.
I used curl on the Ubuntu VM and it's still able to see other devices (such as TrueNAS Core). I can also use an SSH tunnel to access these other devices. But I can't access them via WireGuard like I usually would.
The only thing that I'm aware of changing since the last time I rebooted the Ubuntu VM is that I've installed Pterodactyl Wings within Docker. This adds a Docker Bridge interface. (Subnet 172.19.0.0/16, gateway 172.19.0.1) But as far as I can tell there's no reason this should conflict with the networking of WireGuard.
I don't really know where to start with troubleshooting this issue and I'd love any advice you might have.
EDIT: As you can see below, I'm using PostUp / PostDown commands to ensure IP tables is correctly handling MASQUERADE. My WireGuard subnet (10.8.0.1/24) does not conflict with anything else on my network. I do have multiple peers configured, and each has a unique /32 within this subnet. And my client's AllowedIPs is set to route traffic to 192.168.10.0/24.
While my client is connected, I am also able to successfully ping 10.8.0.2 from both the server and the client. I can also ping one client from another client.
Since I can connect to 192.168.10.240, this presumably means that the WireGuard server is providing a route from 10.8.0.0/24 to 192.168.10.0/24. It seems the issue occurs when the traffic needs to physically leave that host. So perhaps the issue is with my USG router (but I didn't change anything near the time that I rebooted my VM) or perhaps Ubuntu is not accepting the relevant traffic from the NIC?
I don't know how to troubleshoot this.
EDIT2: I physically connected a client device to my homelab network and it was able to access all servers as expected. But then I activated WireGuard (while still physically connected) and I lost access to all servers except 192.168.10.240. So this indicates that the WireGuard client is definitely routing traffic to these addresses through the tunnel.
I also tried temporarily using a very minimalist iptables config (see below) but this resulted in no change.

WireGuard Server Configuration:
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [redacted]
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
[Peer]
PublicKey = [redacted]
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32


WireGuard Client Configuration:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = [redacted]
Address = 10.8.0.2/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = [redacted]
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.1/24, 192.168.10.0/24
Endpoint = example.org:51820

Network details:

Subnet 192.168.10.0/24
Gateway 192.168.10.1 (UniFi USG)
DHCP range 192.168.10.100 - 192.168.10.199

Relevant hosts:

TrueNAS server (physical) - 192.168.10.221
QuickSync server (physical) - 192.168.10.222
IPMI for TrueNAS (physical) - 192.168.10.231
Ubuntu VM hosted on TrueNAS server - 192.168.10.240 (WireGuard server!)
Docker container on QuickSync server (macvlan) - 192.168.10.241

Tracert:
C:\Users\test>tracert 192.168.10.221

Tracing route to 192.168.10.221
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *       25 ms    20 ms  10.8.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.

Ping from server to client
PING 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=20.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=27.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=19.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=27.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=27.2 ms
^C
--- 10.8.0.2 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.409/24.223/27.209/3.536 ms

Ping from client to self (on VPN)
Pinging 10.8.0.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.8.0.2:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Ping from client to other client
Pinging 10.8.0.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=127
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 10.8.0.2:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 39ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 48ms

Minimalist iptables config
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Apr 14 14:57:35 2024
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [119314:15037722]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [169491:32755967]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 14 14:57:35 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Apr 14 14:57:35 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [222:56161]
:INPUT ACCEPT [14:1327]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [248:13567]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [256:16075]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 14 14:57:35 2024


Try running sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding; value should be 1. Try running iptables-save (as root); follow the FORWARD chain from top to bottom to see if any rules that may apply to your WireGuard traffic will REJECT or DROP it before it gets to your ACCEPT rules.

@JustinLudwig sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding is set to 1. My iptables rules were complex so I temporarily used a simplified set of rules (I've edited the post to include these rules) but I was still unable to connect to any other servers via WireGuard.

Is the WireGuard server's LAN interface (ie interface with address 192.168.10.240) still named eth0? Also try running nft list ruleset (as root) to double-check that it's empty (or just reflects your iptables ruleset). Finally try running ip rule to double-check that there are no rules other than simple lookups for the local/main/default tables.

@JustinLudwig Huh. My interface is called enp0s4, not eth0. But I think it's always been called that. I wonder how this ever worked...
After correcting the interface name I'm back online!
Do you want to put all the stuff you asked in your comments in an answer so I can pay out the bounty?

Likely either the LAN interface name changed on the WireGuard server, or you had previously added an adhoc iptables rule to NAT connections forwarded to it, which was lost when the server was rebooted.
The general pattern for masquerading WireGuard connections from a WireGuard server to its LAN are, on the server:

Enable the kernel parameter for forwarding (eg sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1).
Allow forwarding of WireGuard connections through the firewall (eg iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT and the reverse)
NAT those forwarded connections to the LAN (eg iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE)

And on the clients:

Add the LAN subnet to their AllowedIPs setting.

You had all those things -- but you had the wrong interface name in your NAT rule; eth0 is the traditional name for the first Ethernet interface, but on many Linux distros, it may be something different.
A good set of commands to run on the server to check what might be wrong are:
sudo wg
sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding
ip address
ip route
ip rule
sudo iptables-save
sudo nft list ruleset

If all else fails, you can also try running tcpdump on each host (like this Troubleshooting WireGuard with Tcpdump article describes) to try to identify exactly where traffic is being dropped.
